# comparing the values in 2 arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have 2 arrays. One is a list of letters, whereas the other is inputted by the user. I'm trying to write a function to compare these 2 arrays to see if a keyboard matches, e.g if user enters BOB, the program will store BOB in an array and will compare BOB to the other array and check if BOB is inside it.

```
char bigarray []= "asdlkfjas;ldkfjas;kldf";

printf("Please enter the number of letters: ");
scanf("%d",&dna);

printf("Enter %d characters ", num);

for (int i = 0; i < dna; i++)
{
     scanf(" %c", &input[i]); 
     searchFunc ();
}
```

Once I get user input for the characters, I scan the characters and store it in an array. Now, my searchFunc function will compare the 2 arrays and see if theres a match and return the index value of where its found. I'm not sure with how to write this function to compare the values and what parameters I must pass.

I believe I need to write an nested for loop to go through both arrays, but not entirely sure how to do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bigarray []; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < dna; j++) {
  if (bigarray [i] == dna [i])
      printf("found at %d", bigarray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats this `char bigarray [asdfjasl;kdfja;sdkljf];` ?

Comment: highly insecure code.

Comment: Do you mean `char bigarray [] = "asdfjasl;kdfja;sdkljf";`?

Comment: Could you describe your comparisom function more specifically, please?

Comment: please check my update. Thats how much I got up to. @cad

Comment: `printf("Enter %d characters ", num);` -- Did you mean `printf("Enter %d characters ", dna);`? And `for (int i = 0; i < bigarray []; i++) {` won't compile. As for the answer, use `strstr`.

Comment: If you use `strstr`, be warned that the array `input[]` is not 0-terminated as a string.

Comment: What's this `i < bigarray[]` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

A nested loop works, but the standard library provide `strchr()` whihc simplifies your nearly correct code.

> The `strchr` function locates the first occurrence of c (converted to a char) in the string pointed to by `s`.  C11dr §7.24.5.2 2

Search for each letter of user input against the reference string.

```
int Compare(const char *ref, const char *user_data, int user_data_length) {
  for (int i=0; i<user_data_length; i++) {
    if (strchr(ref, user_data[i]) == NULL) return 0;  // at least 1 missing
  }
  return 1; // all found
}

....
printf("All there? %s\n", Compare(bigarray, input, dna) ? "Yes" : "No");
```